# Old FireBug required in Firefox 49.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox, console, firebug

I've installed the firefox latest version but the old firebug is removed. I install the old firefox (49.0.1) but facing the same problem I do not find the firebug in any URL and add-ons.

Comment: why negative voting?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: suggest me any website. where i can put the question

Answer (score 1):

Developers Tools are now an integral part of FireFox which makes FireBug obsolete.

Tools > Web Developer

Answer (score 0):

If you need/want to use Firebug with firefox 49.0.1 (or even v56)

Install the addon ["Classic Add-ons Archive"](https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases) and from this addon you can install Firebug 2.0.19 or any other legacy addon that Mozilla has removed from its web.